# Rviz 2D alternative?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,
I would like to use a 2D User Interface for ROS, does it exist? As far as I'm concerned, rviz is the only there is (because gazebo/stage are simulators).
Why do I want to use something else than rviz? Mainly, because even specifying the topic of the data (position, laser ranging, speed control), it doesn't recognize it. From the troubleshooting page from RVIZ I found out I have to include my data into a tf, something that sounds very complicated and (maybe) unnecessary.

Is there any way out? And if there's not, any tutorials on how to turn my data/topic into a tf?

Cheers,

**Update:** On a nutshell, what I'm doing is fairly simple: 3 different cases of sending data through topics in ROS (one topic). I have a task_talker and a task_listener (based on the tutorial codes, just modifying the type of messages sent). Task_talker publishes the parameter into the topic and task_listener subscribes to it. The different tasks are as follows (with its parameters):

1. Position sending using ***geometry_msgs/Pose2D***
2. Laser ranging sending using ***sensor_msgs/LaserScan***
3. Speed Control using ***geometry_msgs/Twist***.

I would post the code as well, but it also includes a different OS from ROS that would only further confuse readers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29346/rviz-2d-alternative?/) by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2012-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since rviz only shows messages of type PoseStamped, you should convert this Pose2D to [PoseStamped](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseStamped.html) or to Odometry (in case you need to show multiple poses)

We have a program to convert from Pose2D to Odometry [iri_msg_to_odom pose2d_to_odom](https://devel.iri.upc.edu/pub/labrobotica/ros/iri-ros-pkg/stacks/iri_odometry_publisher/trunk/iri_msg_to_odom/). The instructions to download our repository are here: Download [IRI ROS stack](http://wikiri.upc.es/index.php/Download_IRI_ROS_software) (you can download only the iri-ros core and then checkout the iri_msg_to_odom package.

the other way is code it by yourself (it's not difficult):)

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2012-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on 2012-05-03**:
So by putting the pose information into PoseStamped from Pose2D (without filling the header or the quaternion of pose), will rviz be able to recognize the input?

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2012-05-07**:
I think you should fill these fields, at least frame_id and orientation (for example with .x = .y = .z = 0, .w = 1)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Mainly, because even specifying the topic of the data (position, laser ranging, speed control), it doesn't recognize it.

Are you using the right messages to pass the data?
You can find the right messages to use here [RViz Display Types](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes)

> From the troubleshooting page from RVIZ I found out I have to include my data into a tf, something that sounds very complicated and (maybe) unnecessary.

You can set the Global frame to the data you want to visualize, for example, if your data are LaserScan messages you should change the global frame to the frame_id of this message (usually /laser)

> Is there any way out? And if there's not, any tutorials on how to turn my data/topic into a tf?

You can publish static tf transforms using the [tf static transform publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher)

For instance if you have a Pose and a LaserScan to be shown you can publish two static transforms one from /base to /pose and the other from /base to /laser and set rviz global frame with /base

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2012-03-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1